# pandas - Grouped weighted Bar Chart

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following DataFrame consisting of 10 rows.

```
d = {
    'grp_id':[1,2,1,1,1,3,1,1,4,1],
    'weight':[1,2,1,1,1,3,1,1,4,4],
    'value': [1,2,1,3,2,1,4,1,1,3]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

A weighted histogram can be achieved with

```
df['value'].hist(histtype='bar', weights=df['weight'])
```

An unweighted bar chart grouped by *grp_id* with

```
df['value'].hist(by=df['grp_id'], histtype='bar')
```

[image]

I'd like to combine the two and plot a *weighted* bar chart grouped by *grp_id*.
I've tried the following 2 methods without success since for both I get a `ValueError`.

```
df['value'].hist(by=df['grp_id'], weights=df['weight'], histtype='bar')
df['value'].hist(by=df['grp_id'], weights='weight', histtype='bar')
```

> ValueError: weights should have the same shape as x

The temporary solution I'm using is the following.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)
for ax,(idx, grp) in zip(axes.flatten(), df.groupby('grp_id')):
    grp['value'].hist(weights=grp['weight'], histtype='bar', ax=ax)
```

However, I would like to ask if there is a direct way to do it with pandas.

Comment: Can you give us the desired output of your example?

Comment: Hi, the code to produce the output is given in the last part of the question. In practice, it corresponds to a subplot for each group each with a weighted bar chart.

Comment: Because i didn't understand, do you want to group grp_id and count distinct values in weight and value columns?

Answer (score 0):

I would firstly create a new data frame storing weighted values:

```
df['weighted_values'] = df.weight*df.value
df = df.groupby('grp_id')['weighted_values'].sum().to_frame().reset_index()
```

You can use seaborn to plot the final barchart aesthetically:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(x = 'grp_id', y = 'weighted_values', data=df)
```

[image]